# How can I add ZIP file to my program exe file?

Tags: c#, zip

I want to add a ZIP archive to my EXE file. Because I wan to move only exe (not exe and zip) to another PC and program exe on another PC must create the same ZIP file.
I was trying to add ZIP as embedded resource.But when I move exe from debug folder to another PC, it doesn't work.

Comment: You shouldn't zip only the EXE, you should also zip other files such as your config file, and any other DLL that resides in the same Debug folder.

Answer (score 0):

In the attached screenshot, I have illustrated which files to zip along with your final executable.

[image: Demo for including other files in the ZIP]

Comment: I don't need to archivate my Exe.I need to add existing Zip file to my exe.Because I wanna use the only exe after that(don't carry along ZIP file )